# Function on form submit works only once [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have made a search products app where I have form 3 fields from which I want to search the products. On submission the searchProducts() function is called which sends a get request to my api with request parameters it got from the form fields.

Problem - My form works only once. I can search only once and then I have to refresh the page to search again. Sometimes it works twice but not more than that. I do not know why.

I want to keep calling the searchProducts() function whenever the form is submitted. I want to work it again and again without refreshing the page as a user can search multiple times.

My searchProducts() function / Component -

```
export class SearchproductComponent implements OnInit {


  isAuthenticated(){
    return this.userService.isAuthenticated();
  }

  productSearchForm = this.fb.group({
    productCode: [, []],
    name: [, []],
    brand: [, []],
    priceLow: [,[]],
    priceHigh: [, []]
  })

  get productCode(){
    return this.productSearchForm.get('productCode');
  }

  get name(){
    return this.productSearchForm.get('name');
  }

  get brand(){
    return this.productSearchForm.get('brand');
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public productsService: ProductsService, public userService: UserserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  searchProducts(){

    let name = this.productSearchForm.controls.name.value!
    let brand = this.productSearchForm.controls.brand.value!
    let productCode = this.productSearchForm.controls.productCode.value!

    if (name && brand === null && productCode === null){
      let response = this.productsService.getProductsByName(name)
      console.log(response)
    }
    if (name && brand && productCode === null){
      let response = this.productsService.getProductsByNameAndBrand(name, brand)
      console.log(response)
      console.log("Name and Brand Working");
    }
    if (name && brand && productCode){
      let response = this.productsService.getProductsByNameAndBrandAndProductCode(name, brand, productCode)
      console.log(response)
      console.log("Name and Brand and Product Code Working")
    }
```

It has more functions but you get the idea.

My searchProducts html file -

```
<div class="search-form">
    <form (ngSubmit)="searchProducts()" [formGroup]="productSearchForm" name="productSearch" class="form-inline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="product-code" class="form-label">Product Code: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product-code" name="product-code" formControlName="productCode">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" formControlName="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="brand" class="form-label">Brand: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" name="brand" formControlName="brand">
            </div></div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 mb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Search</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="filterAnother()">Search Another</button>

            </div>
           
            <div class="col-10 mb-3" *ngIf="isAuthenticated();">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-3" (click)="filterByPrice()">Filter by Price</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="filterAnother()">Filter Another</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 mu-2">
                        <label for="price-range" class="form-label price-range-label">Price Range: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price-range-low" name="price-low" formControlName="priceLow">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price-range-high" name="price-high" formControlName="priceHigh">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want searchProducts() to work again and again. It only works once.

My UI looks like this -
[image: UI]

I tried adding another button search another to run function onclick but still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `if` function, you are checking if all your inputs are null:

`if (name && brand === null && productCode === null)`

UPDATE:

You can do the following instead since you only search when there is a name typed in:

`if (name !== null && brand === null && productCode === null)`

So if you only search nulls, you won't get a response from your service I imagine. You're also doing the same check in the second `if`, just with a different logic:

`if (name && brand && productCode === null)`

UPDATE:

You can do the following instead since you are searching whenever there is a name & brand typed in:

`if (name !== null && brand !== null && productCode === null)`

Your third `if` function works since you are making sure that all of them exist, with this logic you should be able to search, but only if all 3 inputs have values, you can try in the link below:

`if (name && brand && productCode)`

I reproduced your code in StackBlitz and it looks like you need to improve your first 2 `if` statements logic so you can properly search when only one value (or 2) is being passed to angular service. Here is the StackBlitz link if you want to review it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ywlaqz?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

Comment: Oh right. Do you have any suggestion for improvement? I am thinking of adding null validator but would appreciate something I can put it out in conditions.

Comment: I updated my answer, I will strongly advice you to improve your API endpoint or service to handle multiple search parameters.